# async/await race condition related to `forEach` use?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I have the following async function:

```
async function createDemoContent({ orgId, userId }) {
  const createTag = promisifyMethod(_createTag);
  const tags = {};

  /* ... */
  [
    'marketing',
    'insights',
    'customer-centric',
    'email marketing',
    'click through rate',
    'tests',
    'research',
    'UX'
  ].forEach(async (label) => {
    const tag = await createTag({
      demo: true,
      label,
      orgId,
    });

    tags[label] = tag._id;
  });

  console.log('all tags:', JSON.stringify(tags));
```

And just in case anyone wants to see `promisifyMethod` (it converts a Meteor method to a promisified function call):

```
export function promisifyMethod(method: Object) {
  return (...args: Array<any>) => {
    return new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
      method.call(...args, (error: Object, result: any) => {
        if (!error) resolve(result);
        else reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

For some reason, the `tags` object is shown as being an empty object. There must be something wrong with my usage of `async`/`await` where the `console.log` is being hit before even the first property is added to the `tags` object. But I have several `await` calls above this `forEach` and those seem to work just fine.

This is the code for `createTag`:

```
export const createTag = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'createTag',

  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    demo: { type: Boolean, optional: true },
    label: String,
    orgId: String,
  }).validator(),

  run(args) {
    const tag = new Tag(args);

    tag.save();
    return tag;
  },
});
```

Comment: @JaromandaX Added.

Comment: No, `promisifyMethod` is 100% spot on. I've used it dozens of times before.

Comment: That's an interesting problem. I think you are making the assumption that multiple awaits within a for each should behave like `Promise.all`. But it looks like thats not the case. I would push all of the `createTag` promises to an array and then `await Promise.all(promiseArray)`

Comment: Use Promise.all. Do not use `await` inside loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are calling an async callback function, but is not waiting for it to finish. `forEach` merely executes the function, but does not wait for the promise returned by the async callback to resolve.

You can do:

```
for (const label of labels) {
    const tag = await createTag(args)

    tags[label] = tag._id
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad edit. I could've _sworn_ I've done `for (const x of y)` before and been thrown an error because a const couldn't iterate through the array.

Comment: no worries Balázs Édes